# no data loaded in mysql table;

Tags: mysql

It seems that everything is read properly but no data are loaded, even if the file has got 6 lines not considering the first one.

```
mysql> load data infile 'C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\Uploads\\test2.txt' into table orders
    -> fields terminated by '\t'
    -> ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\ n'
    -> ignore 1 lines;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 0  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Maybe it can help, I'll add the description of my table and a line of the file as example.

```
mysql> describe orders;
+--------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| sys                      | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| client                   | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| are                      | int          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| SaleDocument             | int          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| item                     | int          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| salesdoctype             | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| POtype                   | varchar(15)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| profitcenter             | varchar(15)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| orderquantity            | int          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| quantityunit             | varchar(15)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| material                 | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| MLFB                     | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| GCK                      | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| PCK                      | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| description              | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| orderchannelconsolidated | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| customer                 | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ifa                      | int          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| salesorg                 | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| salesoffice              | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| salesofficename          | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| companycountry           | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| division                 | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| divisiondesc             | varchar(150) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| businessunit             | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| createdby                | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| createdon                | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ordertype                | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ordervolumeeuro          | float        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| eordervolumeeuro         | float        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
30 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

And a line of my txt file looks like this(fields are terminated by a tab):

```
SWP01   100 5180    310799105   1000    ZPCA    DFUE    P50XE2A 1   Piece   8GF9872 8GF9872 P310    5554    DISTRIBUTION TERMINAL BLOCK 4 POLE 100A EDI 1012229 275091843   50Q0    50Q1    LV Direzionale  Italy   QA  SSI LP (SSI045) SI EP   SWE0012S    dic 31 2019 12:00 AM    eOrder - IDOC   53,89   53,89
```

I haven't found solutions all over the blog.

I've tried to solve my problem changing tab to ;

```
mysql> load data infile 'C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\Uploads\\testcorto.txt' into table orders
    -> fields terminated by ';'
    -> lines terminated by '\\r\\n';
ERROR 1265 (01000): Data truncated for column 'ordervolumeeuro' at row 1
```

I've found similar errors on the blog but with no solutions.

I would be very grateful for any kind of help.

Comment: Your published sample data does not appear to be tab delimited I suggest you massage the file before presenting to load data infile.

Comment: Replace DESCRIBE with SHOW CREATE TABLE. Provide first 3-4 rows from source data file (including header line to be skipped) where tabs are NOT replaced with spaces (or are replaced with some original char which is not present in the data).

Comment: *`LINES TERMINATED BY '\ n'`* This is wrong. Excess space in line terminator.

Comment: correcting that the result  is another error, :  ERROR 1265 (01000): Data truncated for column 'eordervolumeeuro' at row 1.

Answer (score 1):

Could be you have an issue with the comma in ordervolumeeuro, eordervolumeeuro

```
53,89   53,89
```

try replace the comma with  dot

```
load data infile 'C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\Uploads\\testcorto.txt' into table orders
-> lines terminated by '\r\n';
-> (@var1, @var2)
-> SET ordervolumeeuro= REPLACE(@var1, ',', '.'), eordervolumeeuro  = REPLACE(@var2, ',', '.')
```

Comment: I know what you are getting at but clearly the file does not have fields terminated by ';' and '\\r\\n' has 2 too many \

Comment: the problem is not the , instead of . in  53,89 because i've tried to change it for the first row, replacing it with a dot and I still have the same error  at row 1, and not at row 2 as I expected

Comment: have tried, just for text,   using  a file with single row  without the comma ..  (the error message could be ambygous)

Comment: fields were terminated with ; , the only way to make it work was by replacing the float type with varchar but i need floats, not varchar

Comment: then  you first import a  temporary table the value with varchar and then with an insert select you can populate the destination table